# How to include a skill into your workout

Tags: workout-routines, bodyweight-exercises

I want to learn handstand and I think that I have the sufficient strength, so my main goal is to learn how to balance.

The problem is that I don’t know how to include it to my workout, I can’t train 1-2 days after my workout, so I should include it at my workout days, but I don’t know when to include it, at the start of the session? or at the end of it, and If I did include it at the start of the session I think it will exhaust me and I wouldn’t be able to complete the other exercises.

By the way I train on Monday and Friday (Pull + Push), and legs on Thursday. If you need to know the exact exercises that I do please tell me.

Comment: The way that works best for me is hitting compound movements first (Bench, Deadlift, Squats). Next I'll do my calisthenics movements (handstand work, planche, front lever, etc). Finally I'll do my isolation work. Currently I am running one compound movement per workout, following that with a type of callisthenic progression training, and following with everything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can definitely include it at the end of your workouts, maybe unless you totally exhausted your shoulders (push days) or are just too exhausted in general. I would suggest this over adding handstands at the beginning of the workout in order to have more energy for the main workout and also be warmed up for the handstands.

Second, unless you are practicing for a long time or are doing something like handstand push-ups, there is no reason not to do it on non-training days. Practicing a few handstands will not be so hard on your muscles that it would hinder recovery substantially (unless you are a pro athlete maybe, where every last bit of recovery may count). I didn't totally understand your training schedule, but I guess it's one day push, one day pull, one day leg (Mon: Push OR Pull / Thu: Legs / Fri: Push OR Pull)? Then you can definitely do it after pull/leg days, and as I said unless you're overdoing it even moderately after push days.

As a side note, if by "I can’t train 1-2 days after my workout" you mean that you are so exhausted you literally can't do any physical activity, you'd be overdoing it. Otherwise, yes you are right you need that recovery time, but as I said a few handstands are still fine, you don't need to basically lie still all day to recover from a workout.

Comment: You misunderstood my workout program, I do push and pull on Monday, legs on Thursday and push+pull on Friday again.

Comment: Oh I see, using push/pull to describe one workout is quite uncommon (since that would make it just an upper body workout), that's why I thought you are talking about separate ones. Either way, you should still be able to practice some handstands on off days and at the end of workouts, especially on/after leg day, but as I said IMO also combined with your other sessions.

Answer (score 3):

I personally think it's best to to do handstands, flips, and other movements where coming up a bit short can result in you landing on your head, before a more strenuous workout. Yes, you learn how to bail, but when you're tired, even that tends to get a little off. If training the handstands makes you too exhausted for the rest of the workout, I'd say that you need to make some adjustments to make it a bit less strenuous.

As a side note, since handstands are as much about balance as muscular effort, it's an excellent skill to "grease the groove" with. Got a few spare minutes between one task and the next? Do your handstand against the wall. Bored in line? Handstand. Playing with the kids? Spontaneous handstand (but be prepared for one of them dashing in to shove you, and learn your bails in different directions so that you can bail without landing on top of them).

Comment: But they cushion the fall and it's character-building!

Comment: Completely agree, skill work first and frequently